# Redis is not working as Php7 session handler

Tags: php, redis, php-7

I have a problem with redis sessions. I install php7, Apache2 etc. to my ubuntu 16.04 machine. I install redis server as welll and it works.

In php, when I use 'files' as php session handler, php works but when I set php session handler to redis and add code 'session_start()' to my php code, it shows 'This page is not working'. Why?

Here is a part of my php.ini file

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini

[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = redis

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth=MYREDISPASS"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if
; your OS has problems with many files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle many sessions.
```

when I execute 'php index.php' in terminal it works.

Comment: Is redis listening via tcp on 127.0.0.1:6379? can you manually connect to it? Also please note: running ``php index.php`` might not start a session and/or use another php.ini (cli vs. apache) file. Did you check that too?

Comment: Yes, I can connect it manually.  After I post this question, I remove all components of php, apache redis etc. and install Ampps.  Then configure redis for ampps' php. It works now. thanks anyway.